# Solving $\log(x) = x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

One can use Taylor series of the log or exp function to get the result that $x = 1$. I was wondering if there is any other simple solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x - \log x$ has derivative $f'(x) = 1 - \frac1x$ which is negative for $x<1$ and positive for $x>1$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly decreasing for $x<1$ and strictly increasing for $x>1$. Since $f(1)=1$ we have $f(x)>1$ for $x<1$ and $x>1$. Therefore, $x=1$ is the only solution to $f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an infinite set of complex solutions (if you already had complex numbers) if you consider different branches of the complex logarithm (Where $k$ denotes the branch):
$$\log(k, x) = x-1$$
$$x=e^{x-1}$$
$$xe^{1-x}=1$$
$$-xe^{-x}=-\frac{1}{e}$$
$$x = -W_k(-\frac{1}{e}) \land k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
where $W_k$ is the $k$-th branch of the $W$-Function.

Note that if you are taking the "main" branch of the logarithm in your equation, there is only one solution: $x = 1$

Comment: I think you have to be a little more careful with that. Branches $k=0$ and $k=-1$ give the double solution $x=1$. But the other branches don't quite make it. The solutions don't verify the original equation. For example, branch one gives $x=-W(1,-1/e)\sim 3.088843016-7.461489286i$. Plugging this into the equation $\ln(x)=x-1$ gives $2.088843016-1.178303978i = 2.088843016-7.461489286i$, which is an absurdity. You might want to revise your answer.

Comment: Well, you are right. But doesn't it depend on which branch of the complex logarithm you are taking? I don't know which branch of log the OP means, when he is writing $\log(x)$

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis The difference between those two values you present are just $2\pi i$ and is related to which branch of the complex logarithm you take: $(\log x)_{\rm branch~k} = \log |x| + i{\rm Arg}(z) + 2\pi k i$

Comment: @AndreiKh, Winther: Precisely. That's why they are NOT solutions to the original equation, for the problem as stated. You are solving the equation $\ln(x)=x-1$ (for the principal branch of $\log$), not the equation $\log(k,x)=x-1$. Note that these solutions are spurious solutions which were introduced when you raised the equation via $\exp(x)$, exactly because $\exp$ is periodic moldulo $2\pi i$.

Comment: Yes, you're right (The $\exp$-function is not injective in $\mathbb{C}$), but I wasn't familiar with the complex-log notation $\log(k,x)$ at the point of writig.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x>1$. Then $$\log x=\int_1^x t^{-1}dt <\int_1^x dt = x-1$$

Now suppose $0<y<1$. Then $$\log y=\int_1^y t^{-1}dt >\int_1^y t^{-2}dt=1-1/y$$

Now set $y=x^{-1}, x>1$ to get $\log x < 1-x$ on $0<x<1$. Equality is clear at $x=1$. In particular we have proven that for $x>0$ $$1-x^{-1}\leqslant \log x\leqslant x-1$$

with equality iff $x=1$. This proves in particular that $\log '1=1$, i.e. that $$\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{\log(1+h)}h=1$$